# After the last update to Xcode I can’t save user data to Firestore like before

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

As the title says after updating to Xcode 15 and [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 10.19.1 I can’t save User date, I use Sign in with Apple authentication
The function was working fine before the update.

This is the code:

Model:

```
struct User: Hashable, Codable {
var uid : String
var name, uniqname, profileImage: String
var Score : Int 

var data:[String: Any] {
    ["name":name,
     "uniqname":uniqname,
     "profileImage":profileImage,
     "Score":Score,
     "uid": uid
    ]
}  }
```

View Model:

```
init() {
    fetchCurrentUser()
}


func fetchCurrentUser()  {
    guard let uid = FireBaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {return}

    FireBaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to fetch current user: \(error)")
            return
        }
        guard let data = snapshot?.data() else {
            print("No Data Found  \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            return

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let uid = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
            let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let uniqname = data["UniqName"] as? String ?? ""
            let score = data["Score"] as? Int ?? 0
            let profileImage = data["profileImage"] as? String ?? ""

           self.user = User(uid: uid, name: name, uniqname: uniqname, profileImage: profileImage, Score: score)
            
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the function to save user data to Firestore when they Sign in with Apple:

```
func CreatUser() {

guard let uid = FireBaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {return}

let userData = User(uid: uid ,name: "", uniqname: "", profileImage: "", Score: 0)
let userId = vm.user?.uid
     if userId != ""{
         self.vm.isLoggedin = true
        print("✨")
    } else {FireBaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("Users").document(uid).setData(from: userData.data){
                    err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print(err.localizedDescription,"")
                    } else {
                        print("Help! First Time!")
                    }
                }
        }  }
```

Is there some error in the last update or error in the code?

Note: the code with execute “print("No Data Found  (error?.localizedDescription)”)”   from the View Model and the “error?.localizedDescription “ will be nil

I tried updating Package to the last update: File->Package->Update to Latest Package Versions, didn't work.

Comment: Is it possible that your value of `uid` is invalid when that code runs?  Try logging various values to see whether you are passing valid values to the Firebase API calls.  Without knowing details of any type of errors, it is nearly impossible to guess as to what the error might be.

Comment: It's valid, the most absurd thing is the Users Collection have Sub-colllection of Library to add movie, if I ignored the problem and tried to add something to the library the sub collection will be created under the uid of the current user with no errors, but user data won't be saved to the Users collection no matter what I do.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. How do you know that the `uid` value is valid?  I don't understand what you mean by "User Collection have sub-collection"....collections don't have subcollections, only Documents have subcollections.  Recognize that the authentication process is ASYNCHRONOUS and personally I NEVER use the code of `auth.currentUser` because that code might execute before authentication has completed.  Instead I use the `onAuthStateChanged` listener to capture the `user` value on completion of login, then I only use that `user` value throughout my app.

Comment: Sorry for th confusion, I'm not good at explaining. What you said right, the Users collection-> user document have sub collection named library, when user sign in for the first time the user data (name etc.) won't be added to User collection (Authentication works) but when adding movie to the library the sub collection will be created under the current user uid. I will try your method.

Comment: Always just print `err`, not `localizedDescription`

Comment: @Rena it might be better to have a more direct dialog about this issue if you are having difficulties summarizing it in a SO post.  Consider joining a Firebase community such as the Firebase Community on Slack, or the Firebase Me community on Discord ( https://firebase.me )